# phpseclib, Fatal error: Class 'Net_SSH2' not found

Tags: php, phpseclib

I already googled for fixes but it seems like it dosent work.
I downloaded the 1.0 Version from ther Page, included the Stuff like this:

```
set_include_path('components/phpseclib');
include('Net/SSH2.php');
```

Which results in:

```
 Fatal error: Class 'Net_SSH2' not found in /var/www/web/xxxxx/pages/rootserver.php on line 57
```

My directory structure is the following

Script: `/var/www/web/xxxxx/pages/rootserver.php`

Lib: `/var/www/web/xxxxx/components/phpseclib`

I already tried to put a / or \ infront of Net, more errors as before, still dosent work.

Any idea?

Comment: First thing I'd suggest: try doing `set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'components/phpseclib');`. Typically `.` is in the include_path and you're basically removing it, which could cause a good number  of issues.

Comment: @Neoon It is my problem too. do you find any solution?